# Is it appropriate to say the Asher Yatzar in the bathroom?

Tags: halacha, blessing, asher-yatzar

I found [this information](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birchat_Asher_Yatzar) which says when to recite the blessing. Does one recite it in the bathroom or does one wait until one leaves? The question is motivated by the fact that I heard that it is inappropriate to say a bracha near a toilet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No!  blessing in bathroom is prohibited. But bediavad the beracha is good enough. You need to bless lechatechilla after leaving the bathroom.

**Berachot 24b:**

> והאמר רבה בר בר חנה א"ר יוחנן בכל מקום מותר להרהר בדברי תורה חוץ מבית המרחץ ומבית הכסא
>
> Rabbah B'Bar Hanah has said in the name of R'Johanan: In every place it is permitted to meditate on words of Torah except in the bath and in a privy

**25b:**

> והאמר רב יוסף בר חנינא בית הכסא שאמרו אע"פ שאין בו צואה ובית המרחץ שאמרו אע"פ שאין בו אדם
>
> The din apply even if there is nobody in the  bathroom.

**Mishna Berura OC 84 sk 3:**

> אבל בית הפנימי שכולם עומדים שם ערומים ורוחצין שם הוא מאוס טפי ולכו"ע דינו כבית הכסא
>
> The place in which people are naked and wash is disgusting and has a din of bet hakise (note I wrote a din)

**sk 4:**

> אבל לא וכו' וכן כל הברכות וד"ת אסור שם. ומשמע מדברי הט"ז דבדיעבד אם בירך שם אינו חוזר ומברך וכן בק"ש אין חוזר וקורא

**Conclusion:**  if in the bathroom there is no separated areas all the bathroom is Cheder Hapnimi and is prohibited for blessing and learning Tora.  Bediavad if he already blessed the bracha is good and he must not repeat.  There are several details in poskim in siman 84.

**Explanations:** In poskim we found two reasons, the first, because people there are naked (prohibition to bless in front of Erva), the second because of the dirt and hot vapour level (prohibition to bless and to think divre torah even in silent thinking). An issue is the question: Can a woman bless in the Mikve room? If the place is cold and without vapours<sup>(1)</sup>. Taz ruled that she need to bless in the Mikve room, and count it as a is a Bediavad beracha, because of the fear of hefsek if she bless outside of the mikve. Then she need to bless in the place of the Mikve, even in the Mikne itself.

There are bathroom with a door separating two areas, a "whasing area" in which water is splashed, and there is vapors, and from which is protected the "non washing area", protected from vapors and soiled water. In this conditions, there is lich'ora no problem to bless in "non washing area".

For Bet Hakise, the problem is linked with the cleanliness level of the place. If people leave generally the toilet bowl clean and the floor is also cleaned regularly, there is no permanent bad smell, theoretically there is no longer din of Bet Hakise. If there are clay pipes (e.g. from the top floor appartment) in the room, perhaps may be a din of Avit Shel Tsoa and me raglayim. But the issue of bet hakisse is not needed for the OP.

<sup>(1)</sup> **Kesef Mishne on Rambam Ahava, Kriat Shema, 3, 3, quoted Rabenu Manoach:**

> וכתב ה"ר מנוח וא"ד דכיון דאיסור מרחץ **מפני שעומדים שם ערומים** ה"ה להני מקואות שטובלות בהם הנשים אסור לברך או לקרות בתוכו ולא מסתבר דעיקר איסור המרחץ אינו אלא **משום איסור זוהמא והבלא** דאית ביה על ידי שתשמישו בחמין אבל הני מקואות שהמים שלהן צוננין ליכא זוהמא ומותר וצ"ע דהא לענין מזוזה בית הטבילה כבית המרחץ עכ"ל: ‏

---

See [Peri Megadim](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x655)

---

**The water from the bathroom for netilat Yadaym,** see SA OC 160, 4; Bach 160, See Kaf Hachayim 4, sk 10-11:

> וכ"ש בשתה מהן חזיר וכיוצא בהן שנמאסין בעיני רובא דעלמא
>
> If the water are not disgusting, no problem.

Nowadays, tap water is not disgusting. Additionally to make the netilat inside the bathroom, if the problem is the nacked persons only, no problem.

Comment: Is the bracha then said upon leaving the bathroom?

Comment: Said out of the bathroom exactly

Comment: Though some might say that the בית הכסא of the Gemara isn't the same as modern bathrooms with plumbing.

Comment: @Scimonster I have not mentioned at all the ppsugia of bet hakise

Comment: @kouty You do, in your first source.

Comment: @Scimonster I have not addressed the problem of bet hakise at all

Comment: @I only cited Gemara for the other issue.  It is not obligated to cut the statement of the Gemara

Comment: @kouty I know. Your source talks about the בית הכסא, but you don't show that it has the same law as today's bathroom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49171/discussion-between-kouty-and-scimonster).

Comment: The question was about making a berakha; not thinking about Torah. Consider clarifying.

Comment: @mevaqesh I know, and the first words was for this. But afterwards someone told me someone concerning Bet Hakise, and I was obligated at end to address a bit of each topic. The 2 tsdadim of rabenu Manoach are also nafkaminated concerning hirhure Tora.

Comment: Regardless of the history of the answer, it is not particularly clear and seems to ramble from topic t topic, without a clear progression and explanation of the relevance of different sources, so consider clarifying.

Comment: @mevaqesh I do now a little better.

Comment: @LN6595 thank you, I edited this now in the first line of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to say it in the bathroom or facing the open door to a bathroom.

Comment: What if the door swings outward?

Comment: You should add the source for this.

Comment: @DoubleAA Ya, if you are facing an open door its a problem, no matter which way its opened.

Comment: That's mistaken.

Comment: @DoubleAA Oh, didn't know that. Thought the mishna brura just says opposite an open door.

Comment: If a door swings out you can easily position yourself to see the open door without the bathroom. Why would that be a problem?

Comment: @DoubleAA its not a vort in seeing it, its a vort in being opposite it.

Comment: No it's not, it's a "vort" in seeing into the bathroom. The door is irrelevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think you're wrong on that. You also can't make a bracha near something that smells, I don't think this is a seeing issue.

Comment: Does the door smell? If so, why does it matter if the door is open or not? If not, why are you talking about smell?

Comment: @DoubleAA All I'm saying is that there are halachos based on proximity, not vision. Even if you can't see the toilet you are still across from an open bathroom door.

Comment: And all I'm saying is that's wrong. The door itself is irrelevant. Seeing through the doorway is.